# how to parse below simple json response?

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch

**BackGround : I am trying to parse this simple json response in my SenchaTouch Application.**

json response:

```
{
    "Australia": 
    [
        {
            "Currency": "AustralianDollar",
        }
    ],
    "INDIA": 
    [
        {
            "Currency": "INR"
        }
    ],
    "USA": 
    [
        {
            "Currency": "USD"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch country's currency based on the Country name.

I am trying to fetch the currency value as below.

```
var country = text.Australia.name;
console.log('Country name is'+country);
```

but it gives me error. Can any one please explain on how to parse give country name as input and fetch the currency?

Thank you,
Gendaful

Comment: What's the error? And, how are you getting this response? What's `text`?

Comment: JavaScript has a built-in `JSON.parse()` function. You pass a JSON string, and get the corresponding object back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
var obj = eval("(" + text+ ')');
```

Check out [json.org](http://json.org/) for better/safer ways to do it.

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3eAuf/)

Check out [this compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/json) for using `JSON.parse(text);`.

Comment: No need for eval. Mobile environments [provide `JSON.parse()`](http://caniuse.com/json).

Comment: @MikeBrant Hence my link to json.org.

Comment: There is something the guy who downvoted should know: The only (important) thing json2.js does is checking the input is in fact JSON for security reasons before itself using eval. If you _know_ it is, there is no point avoiding eval. And if you know it is JSON, you gain compatibility at no cost by using eval.

Comment: @xavierm02. There seems to be a lot of that black-and-white-ness around these parts nowadays. "I read somewhere it's bad practice therefore I'll preach to that".

Comment: Thanks Flem.It has helped.

Comment: @flem: Things that _can_ be bad practice in JS are told to be bad practice because of the huge number of noobs running around. But check the source code. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L471 It uses eval because it's the only way of doing it - aside from JSON.parse which basically just adds some security checks. Using eval _is a very bad idea if you don't control the input_ but if you do, you can just use it without any risk. If you explain this to noobs, they understand "JSON parser = eval"...

Answer (score 3):

If `text` is the JSON string you can do this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var australia = obj.Australia;
var aussie_currency = australia[0].Currency;
```

Note that the odd nesting of the object containing `Currency` inside of an array causes the need for the array index reference `[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

In Sencha Touch you should use

```
var object = Ext.decode(text);
```

to convert a json string into an Object.
Then, in your case, since "Australia" in not an object but an array, you need to get the first  element currency by

```
object.Australia[0].Currency;
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thanks for the comment. One small query, How can I pass Australia as a parameter in the above code? I have a list of countries and the selected country will replace the Australia in the above code. Can you please explain on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Hi Gendaful, rememeber that you are working on javascript so you can access object properties by the "." notation or the "[]" one. So, just to be clear, in your case you could write object[<your_selected_country>][0].Currency, where "<your_selected_country> is the variable which contains the wanted country.

Comment: Hi Andrea. For an example,

I am getting the selectedCountry as an I/P parameter to the function as below.
I want to fetch the currency of that country and *Not Hardcode the country*.
I tried the below code but it gives the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

My code is as mentioned in the next comment . Any suggestions?

Comment: onCountrySelected: function (selectedCountry) {
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/SendMoneyData.json',
        success: function(response){
          var text = response.responseText;
          var object = Ext.decode(text);
          var t = object[selectedCountry][0].Currency;
          console.log("Aussie Currency is>>>"+t);

   }

Comment: The problem here is that your object doesn't contain the country you have selected. You have to test that "object[selectedCountry]" exists before to access to its first element.

Comment: Ya. That was an overlook. Thanks a lot for your time. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this if by using JSON.parse(). All browsers does not support this but you can get fallback by using Douglas Crockford implementations at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery's [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

After that you can use:

```
    var text = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
    var currency = text.Australia[0].Currency;
```

Being the jsonString, the one you obtain via JSON.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I downvoted. Using JQuery isn't a bad thing. But including it just for something that simple is a bad practice.

Comment: FYR. I am using sencha. Thanks for the comments.